# Unexpected execution delay for onclick event on a simple burger menu link in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, transition, delay, pure-css

I am setting up a project using the [pure css](https://purecss.io/) library, and I want to use [their responsive side-menu example](https://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/) (the issue is directly visible on this website).

I just found out the issue occurs in Chrome browser but not in Firefox.

When the viewport width is below 768px, the menu is hidden by default thanks to css media-queries.

Opening the menu using the `#menu-link` button works as expected, but closing it is delayed by roughly 300ms without any obvious reason in the code. If any `console.log` is added in the click handler function, it gets displayed after this mysterious 300ms delay. It is like Chrome does not execute the handler before this timing.

Removing the css transitions on the elements does not fix the issue.

Do you know where it comes from, and/or how to make the menu close as soon as the click is triggered? Is this some known issue within Chrome?